# How to optimise a query on a large dataset?

Tags: performance, hadoop, hive, bigdata

My original Query -

```
CREATE TABLE admin.FctPrfitAmt_rpt AS 
SELECT rcn.* FROM 
(SELECT t1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM admin.FctPrfitAmt t2 WHERE t2.scenario_id NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT t3.scenario_id FROM admin.FctPrfitAmt_incr t3)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM admin.FctPrfitAmt_incr) t1) rcn;
```

The issue is that currently this query takes lot of time as the number of records involved are many.

Is there a way to tune this query?

I tried this approach but it does not work -

```
CREATE TABLE admin.FctPrfitAmt_rpt AS
SELECT * FROM admin.FctPrfitAmt t2 
WHERE t2.scenario_id NOT exists (SELECT 1 from  admin.FctPrfitAmt_incr t3 where t2.scenario_id = t3.scenario_id)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM admin.FctPrfitAmt_incr
```

Error - looks like "not exists" is not supported in my version of Hive, so for my approach, I got the below error:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:25 cannot recognize input near 'NOT' 'exists' '(' in expression specification

Comment: **(1)** is `scenario_id` unique in both tables? **(2)** What is the tables' size (rows / bytes)?

Comment: Yes but that query fails ; is there any way I can make "NOT EXISTS" work ?

Comment: Hi, can you answer the two questions in my first comment?

Comment: sorry, i missed this.
#-> hdfs dfs -du -h -s /user/admin/FctPrfitAmt
30.7 G  61.3 G  /user/admin/FctPrfitAmt
[root@itsusraedld05:/root]#
#-> hdfs dfs -du -h -s /user/admin/FctPrfitAmt_incr
2.2 G  4.3 G  /user/admin/FctPrfitAmt_incr                                                                    scenario id is not unique in both the tables

Comment: Your data might be skewed. Please show the results for the following query: `select  scenario_id,pa,pfa,pa*pfa as product
from (
select  scenario_id
       ,count(case when tab = 1 then 1 end) as pa
       ,count(case when tab = 2 then 1 end) as pfa
from    (           select 1 as tab,scenario_id from admin.FctPrfitAmt      as pa
        union all   select 2 as tab,scenario_id from admin.FctPrfitAmt_incr as pfa
        ) t
        
group by scenario_id  
) t
order by product desc
limit   10
; `

Comment: scenario_id pa      pfa                  product
55 15719384 15719384 2.47099E+14
56 11680340 11680340 1.3643E+14
52 11676563 11676563 1.36342E+14
18 16546168 0                  0
17 13759027 0                  0
10 14647519 0                  0
15 18543447 0                  0
13 13058612 0                  0
9 16522128 0                  0
4 14087559 0                  0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your syntax is wrong.
   `NOT EXISTS` should not be preceded by `t2.scenario_id`
2. As we can see, scenario_id is skewed on both tables, wich creates a huge product on joins.

---

```
select  * 
from    admin.FctPrfitAmt   pa
where   not exists 
        (
            select  null

            from   (select  distinct 
                            pfa.scenario_id 

                    from    admin.FctPrfitAmt_incr  pfa
                    ) pfa

            where   pfa.scenario_id = 
                    pa.scenario_id
        )

union all

select  * 
from    admin.FctPrfitAmt_incr
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, it works, but performance wise, it took the same time as the original query.                                                                                                      can you please suggest how can I make it efficient. Explain plan confused me a lot, so was not sure, how to proceed.

Comment: sorry, i missed this. #-> hdfs dfs -du -h -s /user/admin/FctPrfitAmt 30.7 G 61.3 G /user/admin/FctPrfitAmt [root@itsusraedld05:/root]# #-> hdfs dfs -du -h -s /user/admin/FctPrfitAmt_incr 2.2 G 4.3 G /user/admin/FctPrfitAmt_incr scenario id is not unique in both the tables –

Comment: ok, will check, should i use parquet format  and also try or should i bucket on scenario id to help the performance

Comment: Both might improve performance but the main issue is the product of  the scenario_id's

Comment: I created parquet tables and used your suggested query and the performance is better. Thanks a lot. From originial query which took 14 mins in dev environment, new query runs in less than 8 mins. thats amazing, how can i check/validate if the o/p generated by modified query ( data in final reporting table ) and expected o/p ( using original query) is same.

Comment: When you said "Currently this query takes lot, lot of time", you meant 14 minutes?(!)

Comment: in prod it takes more than 40 mins ( so i am testing in dev environment for a sample of data ) now, in my case, this same query is run in loop for more than 30 tables in loop, parametrized,  so  even small optimization will help /go in long time .

Comment: Got it. Could you please share the prod results?

Comment: yes, once this solution gets approved by the architect, i will be migrating to prod soon. many, many thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. P.s. have you tried the new syntax / parquet separately?

Comment: yes, i tried following ways. (1) just your suggested query - 10 mins; (2) orc + snappy + clustering ; with orignial query, same settings and with ur suggested query; (3) parquet - existing query, and parquet with  ur query             best performance was - parquet with ur suggested query , orc + snappy+ clustering with ur query was close second

Comment: hello David, thanks for  assisting me in tuning complicated queries. is there a checklist or link with good practices that i can refer to, which can help me in writing good hive queries ( we are using TEZ now and have to write 100+ queries - hive on HDP)

Comment: Hi @akashsharma, the best tip i can give at this point is moving to Spark :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're better off left joining the 2 tables in the 'select in' portion and filtering out rows that aren't null on the join key.

```
CREATE TABLE admin.FctPrfitAmt_rpt AS 
    SELECT rcn.* FROM 
    (
        SELECT t1.* 
        FROM admin.FctPrfitAmt t1 
        LEFT JOIN admin.FctPrfitAmt_incr t2
        ON t1.scenario_id = t2.scenario_id
        WHERE t2.scenario_id IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM admin.FctPrfitAmt_incr
    ) rcn
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. with so much data, i hope i dont run into memory issues. my goal is to reduce execution time. Should i also try to cluster the data on scenario id. sorry i am new on this topic. so checking.

Comment: I believe it will cluster the data by scenario_id for the join stage regardless because that is the map key for that stage.  You can verify this by appending 'EXPLAIN ' to your query and running that.  To conserve memory, you should also make sure tables are joined in order of smallest to largest.

Comment: Thank you. Incr table is smaller than base table. But will left join work that way. I tried your suggested query. It failed for container limit memory issues :(

Comment: If that's the case, you could right join with the tables in reverse order as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *

from   (select  *
               ,max(tab) over (partition by scenario_id) as max_tab

        from    (           select *,1 as tab from master.FctPrfitAmt
                union all   select *,2 as tab from master.FctPrfitAmt_incr
                ) t
        ) t

where   tab     = 2
     or max_tab = 1
;
```

---

If all your data is consist of primitive types (no arrays, maps etc.),
you can use the following query:

```
select  inline(array(original_rowset))

from   (select  original_rowset
               ,tab
               ,max(tab) over (partition by scenario_id) as max_tab

        from    (           select struct(*) as original_rowset,scenario_id,1 as tab from FctPrfitAmt
                union all   select struct(*) as original_rowset,scenario_id,2 as tab from FctPrfitAmt_incr
                ) t
        ) t

where   tab     = 2
     or max_tab = 1
```

Comment: Please try this. It has the potential to be way faster than the other options. Note that the final result will have 2 additional technical fields (`tab` and `max_tab`) so you might want to replace the outer `*` with the relevant columns.

Comment: ok, thanks, will try and check but in this case ( with additional columns), i cant use this as generic solution for so many tables, if I need to give column names for each table, when its being processed.

Comment: can u please help me understand, what we are trying to do here. i understood your earlier solution. please bear with my questions and i am a rookie..

Comment: `struct(*)` creates a struct with all the table fields. `inline(array(original_rowset))` explodes the struct to separate fields.

Comment: yes, following are the numbers ..Details 
Original query -> Total: 706 mappers 31 reducers; modified query ->                                                            
                          Total - 159 mappers, 18 reducers                                                 CPU time also reduced from 6hrs 50 mins  to 3 hrs 58 mins

Comment: Was is better than the `not exists` solution?

Comment: i didnt try , let me check and come back with some numbers